# NavigationStack push animation disappears after presenting a view with .sheet modifier

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I need to present a view with .sheet modifier in NavigationStack. But the default push animation of NavigationStack will disappear if I present a view with .sheet modifier first. This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI


class Coordinator:ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func pushColorView(){
        path.append("colorView")
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    //@State var path = NavigationPath()  //<-- If I used this code,the app works fine
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path){
           // NavigationStack(path: $path){  //<-- If I used this code,the app works fine
                VStack{
                    Button("present with sheet") {
                        isPresented = true
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                        PopView()
                    }
                    Button("push"){
                        coordinator.pushColorView()
                    //  path.append("colorView") //<-- If I used this code,the app works fine
                    }
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { destination in
                    Color.blue
                }
            }
            .environmentObject(coordinator)
        }
    }
}


struct PopView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Back to Main") {
                dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the push animation disappeared when I tapped [push] button:

[image]

If I remove Coordinator class and use NavigationPath as a @State property , the app works fine.
I learned Flow Coordinator pattern from the following page:
[SwiftUI Flow Coordinator pattern with NavigationStack to coordinate navigation between views (iOS 16 +)](https://medium.com/macoclock/swiftui-flow-coordinator-pattern-with-navigationstack-to-coordinate-navigation-between-views-ios-1a2b6cd239d7)
I tested the demo mentioned in the article，the same error occurs.You can find the demo here:[demo project in the article](https://github.com/michzio/FlowCoordinators-SwiftUI-iOS16)

Why [Flow Coordinator pattern] and [.sheet modifier] break the push animation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code works well for me, on MacOS 13.4, Xcode 14.3, tested on real ios 16 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems. Try moving the
 `.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented)` to outside the `NavigationStack{...}.sheet(...)`.

Comment: Thanks. I can reproduce this bug on iPhone X(iOS 16.4.1) with mac os 13.3.1,  Xcode 14.3. The simulator(iOS 16.4) can also reproduce this bug. I tried to change the code as you suggested, but this bug still occurs.

Comment: I'm not seeing this bug on Xcode 14.3 with iPhone 14 Pro Simulator (iOS 16.4). One difference is my buttons show as highlighted blue but yours are black.

Comment: Oh,Yes. I made a mistake. I used demo code above in the project got from my colleague. And there is other nested NavigationStack.  I'll take a closer look at the code and figure out the cause of the error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have updated my question. Now the bug can be reproduced.

Comment: your new code also works well for me when you move `.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) { PopView() }` outside the `NavigationStack`. Note, you should be using `@StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator()`.

Comment: Thanks. Moving .sheet modifier out of NavigationStack does solve the problem. But the [.sheet modifier] are hidden in lots of child-views in our project, it is not convenient to move all [.sheet modifier] out of NavigationStack. And yes , you are right, I should use StateObject instead of ObservedObject.I will update the code.But that doesn't affect the results.

Comment: As we need to fix this bug in time, I just removed Coordinator class and create an extension of NavigationPath instead.  This approach takes the least amount of time. Maybe [SwiftUI Flow Coordinator pattern] missed something important. Appreciate your kind help! That really helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you. If you hook into `NavigationStack` using `SwiftUI-Introspect` and override the delegate, the delegte's `willShow` and `didShow` also have `animated` set to `NO` so it looks like there is a bug inside `NavigationStack`. I guessing something with CATransaction or first responder. Moving the sheet outside `NavigationStack` also fixed it for me.